# What is the meaning of 'probe' in the Linux command 'modprobe'?

Tags: meaning, technical, terminology

My understanding of `modprobe` is that it is a command to load kernel modules.

Based on this, I'm wondering what the meaning of word *probe* is in general English?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*probe* is from the Latin *probare*, which means "to test, to examine".  It is used to mean an inquiry, or thorough examination, *probing* tends to imply getting inside something to reveal what is hidden, the truth.

A *probe*, as an object, is a device used to look within something else, to see what is veiled in some respect.

In the case of `modprobe`, the purpose of the command ([see the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe)) is to add/remove modules from the kernel at runtime, which often requires an initial "probe" of the internal hardware in order to detect hardware that drivers may rely on, or indeed checking for dependencies to load within the "internals" of the system.